# Live Broadcasting and server-side playlist - LiveStream.com alternative

Tags: video, media-player, streaming

Until now I was on livestream.com with my TV. They had a very good "Studio" which has an option to make a video playlist like as on TV (autopilot - server-side playlist).

Now they launched the new livestream.com and the old livestream is now working too slow. I want to move all my videos and live broadcasts to other free livestreaming platform. I know about uStream but I need to pay to have the option of autopilot (server-side playlist). Do you know other alternative? Or maybe how to make a server-side playlist without broadcasting it from PC (and without buyng a server)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just go to https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events and you're done. Live streams can be added to channels which are optionally paid.